# Provide Workflow Approve/Reject option in InfoPath Form 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

I have created a Leave Authorisation Form using Infopath 2010 and published it to Forms Library. I have also created a SharePoint designer 2010 custom approval workflow and published it to forms library.

User opens the leave form in browser and fills the info and submits the form and workflow is initiated and manager receives a email. Until here its fine.

When the manager opens the Infopath form how can I provide him an option of approving or rejecting the form that will invoke the workflow. I don't want manager to browse the forms library and then selecting the item from the List and then starting the approval workflow.

Is it possible to customise the InfoPath without any custom code?

Comment: how to hide the approval section for users and show it for managers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link it helps you using Infopath create Leave Request

http://jamilhaddadin.com/2011/12/03/implementing-workflow-using-infopath-2010-and-sharepoint-designer-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's very much possible..
Logically you can have a section containing a dropdown for approve/ Reject. 
This section will only be visible to managers. When manager will open the form he will be able to see the dropdown and will choose either Approve or Reject. You can then initialize workflow according to the approval status option.

In case of any help please let me know..

**EDIT**

@Avinash plz have a look into this article http://www.edutechnow.com/?p=1376 to achieve what u want.

Comment: How will you call the workflow from infopath. I don't want to write any custom code.

Comment: u can trigger the workflow on submission of a form. in the workflow u can check the field's value and perform the required action.

Comment: Could you give some references/links

Comment: plz refer this msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414204.aspx